# Magento 2: Can we create a product attribute without patch with the declarative schema?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, declarative-schema

I want to create a product attribute **without** patch with the declarative schema.
Example would be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can create product attribute from the Magento admin panel.

Navigate to stores > under Attribute title click on Product

You will find add new attribute button on the right top corner.

Also, make sure to assign that attribute o attribute set and do reindex